# charts_flutter - How to change the Bar Color automatically

Tags: flutter, dart, charts

I'm using `charts_flutter` plugin and  I'm having a problem on changing the color of the bars in charts
Is there anyway to change the color of the bar automatically in chart without hardcoding it?, because my data for my chart is flexible and you can't hard code the colors for it.

Here's how I put legends and data for my chart

**code:**

```
 _list.add(new RedeemedToday.fromJson(valueMap));
    
        newLegends.add(charts.Series<RedeemedToday, String>(
          id: '${redeemedToday[index].couponName}',
          data: _list,
          domainFn: (RedeemedToday sales, _) =>
              xValue(redeemedToday[index].whenAdded.toString()),
          measureFn: (RedeemedToday sales, _) => redeemedToday[index].total,
        ));
```

Here's what the default color looked like:

[image]

I want something colorful like this:

[image: right]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you set **colorFn**: (_,__)=>charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(blue) in newLegends.add()

Exp:

```html
Can you set **colorFn**: (_,__)=>charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(blue) in newLegends.add()


Exp: _seriesData.add(
        charts.Series(
          data: data1,
          domainFn: (Pollution pollution,_)=> pollution.place,
          measureFn: (Pollution pollution,_)=> pollution.quality,
          id: 'Colum Charts SSE',
          fillPatternFn: (_,__)=>charts.FillPatternType.solid,
          colorFn: (_,__)=>charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(orange),// Legend color
         fillColorFn: (Pollution pollution,_)=> charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(orange), //column color.
        )
    );

I hope, this is help you.
```

I hope, this is help you.[enter image description here][1]

=> this is result:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nazTx.jpg